Package new_version_plus:android references com.codesfirst.new_version_plus:android as the default plugin, but the package does not exist,
Hello I just upgraded my flutter application to 3.6.0, previously I was using new_version package to show the update popup but as it is no longer maintained I just switched to new_version_plus but I am getting this error in my debug console both for android and ios
Package new_version_plus:android references com.codesfirst.new_version_plus:android as the default plugin, but the package does not exist, or is not a plugin package. Ask the maintainers of new_version_plus to either avoid referencing a default implementation via platforms: android: default_package: com.codesfirst.new_version_plus or create a  plugin named com.codesfirst.new_version_plus.
This is my implementation
final newVersion = NewVersionPlus(
    androidId: "mypackagename",
);
final status = await newVersion.getVersionStatus();

//show popup
if (status.canUpdate == true) {
...
}

everything is working fine but I am getting the warning in the debug console, is there any solution?
Using new_version_plus: ^0.0.12
